# tensorflow-ranking input data in numpy array format

Tags: tensorflow, ranking

So far all the examples I can find for Tensorflow Ranking only take sparse features, I already have a data set pre-processed to numpy array in following format:

```
relevance, query, feature_1, feature_2, ... feature_100
   2,      "a",       0.1,         0.2, ...  0.15
   1,      "a",       0.2,        0.21, ...  0.15
```

I'm looking at this example, where it reads in libsvm data and returned a feature dictionary where each key is the feature column name: https://github.com/tensorflow/ranking/blob/master/tensorflow_ranking/examples/tf_ranking_libsvm.py#L136
But then it gets flattened to a dimension of `[query_size * list_size, feature_count]` before feeding in the graph.
https://github.com/tensorflow/ranking/blob/master/tensorflow_ranking/examples/tf_ranking_libsvm.py#L323

Do I have to reformat my data in order to use tensorflow ranking?
I see `example_feature_columns` is used in `encode_listwise_features` and `encode_pointwise_features`, Is creating `example_feature_columns` a must for tf ranking?

Comment: Eventually I ended up using the loss function directly instead of trying to reformatting my training data format
```
loss_fn = tfr.losses.make_loss_fn("pairwise_logistic_loss")
loss = loss_fn(logits=predicted_y, labels=y_true, features={})
```
https://github.com/tensorflow/ranking/issues/128